# Given a piecewise CDF find the probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say I am given a function $F(x) = \begin{cases} 1 - \frac{1}{(x+1)^3} & x \ge \frac{1}{4} \\ 0 & x < \frac{1}{4} \end{cases}$

I know the CDF is has a discontinuity the book gives this problem under continuous CDF problems. I know is $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(x) dx$.

So for $Pr(X = \frac{1}{4}) = \int_0^{0.25} \frac{3}{(1+x)^4} = 0.488$ this matches the $F(0.25)-F(0.2499) = 0.488 - 0$

I am uncertain in this approach. Specifically because the bounds seem wrong.

Getting a little more complex $Pr(X>\frac{3}{4}) = 1- \int_{0.25}^{0.75} \frac{3}{(1+x)^4} + F(\frac{3}{4}) \delta(x-\frac{1}{4}) dx = 1 - F(\frac{1}{4}) = 0.187$.

Moving onto and where my understanding breaks down is $Pr(-0.5 < X \le 0.5)$.

I know it should be $F(0.5) - F(-0.5) = 0.703704 - 0$ however the integral being $\int_{0.25}^{0.75} \frac{3}{(1+x)^4} + F(\frac{1}{4}) \delta(x-\frac{1}{4}) dx$ seems so wrong.

When examine if my probability density function $f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{3}{(1+x)^4} + F(\frac{1}{4}) \delta(x-\frac{1}{4}) & x \ge \frac{1}{4} \\ 0 & x < \frac{1}{4} \end{cases}$ integrates from $-\infty \to \infty$ to equal one it does not.

I know I must be doing something wrong. Any help why or where I have gone astray is appreciated.

I am also having troubling knowing how to set up $Pr(X<4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(X=1/4)=P(X \leq 1/4)-P(X<1/4)=F(1/4)-\lim_{x \to 1/4^-} F(x).$$

So no integral is required. No integral is required in the second or third parts, either. All of these things can just be read off directly from the CDF, using formulae like the one above.

---

This is a technicality more for visitors to this question rather than for the OP. My formula assumes the right-continuous convention for the CDF, i.e. $F(x)=P(X \leq x)$. This is the far more common convention in the literature in general, but there is literature that uses the left-continuous convention. The $F$ in the OP is right-continuous, so this convention is appropriate for this question.

Comment: The application of a limit makes so much sense. It matches the way I calculated naively. Does it make sense to use the same approach for $Pr(X < 4)$? I get 0.992 by that method. I’d still like to calculate the PDF $f(x)$ since the book makes show of that. Was my approach in the OP correct?

Comment: @TBD The same approach works for $P(X<4)$, but at that point there is no discontinuity so the limit and the function value will just be the same. As for the PDF, you can find it. It will be the distributional derivative of $F$. This is $F'$ where $F'$ exists (which is everywhere except $1/4$). You then add $P(X=1/4) \delta(x-1/4)$ to that.